# Invalid placeholder error when using xml path as template in python string template

Tags: python, string, templates

Below is mwe:

```
from string import Template
key_val = {'a/b/c': 1}
ans = Template('val of ${a/b/c}').substitute(key_val)
```

This gives error:

```
ValueError: Invalid placeholder in string: line 1, col 8
```

However, if I replace forward slash with underscore, then it works fine.
Escaping the forward slash by appending backslash doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings), the default regular expression for the placeholder value is `[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*`, which means that a `/` character is not allowed. If you want to allow this, you should subclass `Template` and redefine the `idpattern` expression:

```
from string import Template

class MyTemplate(Template):
    idpattern = r"[_a-z][_a-z0-9/]*"  # allowing forward slash

key_val = {'a/b/c': 1}
ans = MyTemplate('val of ${a/b/c}').substitute(key_val)
```

Demo:

```
In [8]: from string import Template

In [9]: class MyTemplate(Template):
   ...:     idpattern = r"[_a-z][_a-z0-9/]*"  # allowing forward slash
   ...:     

In [10]: key_val = {'a/b/c': 1}

In [11]: ans = MyTemplate('val of ${a/b/c}').substitute(key_val)

In [12]: ans
Out[12]: 'val of 1'
```